# How to make new visidata column that is filled with column name of max of other columns (argmax)

Tags: python, visidata

In VisiData, is there a way to quickly make an argmax column, i.e. a column that contains the column name of the maximum of a set of columns?

I've done it the pedestrian way but this is cumbersome:

1. Make a new column that is a list of the columns I want to do the argmax of (my columns are named `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) with `=` followed by:

   ```py
   [A,B,C,D]
   ```
2. Rename that column via `^` to something like `collist`
3. Create new argmax column with `=` followed by the following expression:

   ```py
   ["A","B","C","D"][collist.index(max(collist)]
   ```

Is there a better way? I'd love to just select a set of columns and run something like `argmax` on it.